# Ember: How to cleanly replace model data and have progress indicators

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a certain route that shows a list of projects, and it gets initial data from my RESTAdapter based on who the user is.

I am now implementing a search function that will issue a new API call so the user can get records besides the default ones for them, and the response should replace the model for that route. I have all that working, but I'm not sure how to do a loading or progress indicator (as the response from the database could potentially take 5-10 seconds depending on the amount of data). I know about loading substates, but in this case I'm not transitioning between routes. I just want to have at minimum a spinner so the user knows that it's working on something.

Would anyone that's done this before be willing to share how they handled a)replacing the model with new data, and b)keeping the user informed with a spinner or something?

**Form action called when user clicks the Search button**

```
searchProjects: function() {
  var query = this.get('queryString');
  if (query) {
    var _this = this;
    var projects = this.store.find('project', {q: query});
    projects.then(function(){
      _this.set('model', projects);
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> a) replacing the model with new data

You don't need to do anything. If you sideload records properly from the backend, Ember will automatically update them on the frontend.

> b) keeping the user informed with a spinner or something

The loading substate is an *eager* transition. Ember also supports *lazy* transitions via the `loading` event.

You can use that event in order to display the spinner.

Here's an example from the [docs](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#event_loading):

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  actions: {
    loading: function(transition, route) {
      showSpinner();

      this.router.one('didTransition', function() {
        hideSpinner();
      });

      return true; // Bubble the loading event
    }
  }
});
```

## UPD1

> I need to do at least what I'm doing right? Setting the model to the response?

You need to reflect the search in the URL via [query params](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.13.0/routing/query-params/). This will let the router *automatically* update the model for you.

> what I would put in showSpinner to affect stuff on the page (like, can I use jQuery to show or hide a spinner element?), or show the actual loading substate.

I would set a property on that page's controller:

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  queryParams: {
    search: {
      refreshModel: true
    }
  },
  model () {
    return new Ember.RSVP.Promise( resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
  },

  actions: {
    loading (transition, route) {

      this.controller.set('showSpinner', true);

      this.router.one('didTransition', () => {
        this.controller.set('showSpinner', false);
      });

      return true;
    }
  }
});

App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  queryParams: ['search'],
  search:      null,
  showSpinner: false,
});
```

Demo: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/poxika/2/edit?html,js,output

Or you could simply put the spinner into the loading template, which will hide obsolete data:

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/poxika/3/edit?html,js,output

Or you could put your spinner into the loading template:

Comment: Sweet, thanks! When you say "reflect in the URL" do you mean that in my search function I should just transition to the route? Or should I remove that search function in the controller and just do a linkTo on my search button?

Comment: Your search function should not exist in the first place. Have the user update query params, have the route load new model for new query params.

Comment: I need an action for the button though, because there's potentially too much data to call the API for every key press.

Comment: Well, then have a different set of attrs to store user input and copy their values to queryparam'ed attrs on button press.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85427/discussion-between-redoctober13-and-lolmaus-andrey-mikhaylov).

Answer (score 0):

Just in case others want to see, here's my working code based on @lolmaus's answers.

These Docs pages were helpful as well
[Route's queryParams](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#property_queryParams) and [Find method](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_find)

**Controller**

```
//app/controllers/project.js
export default Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  queryParams: ['q'],
  q: null,

  actions: {
    searchProjects: function() {
      var query = this.get('queryString');
      if (query) {
        this.set('q', query);
      }
    }
  }
})
```

**Route**

```
export default Ember.Route.extend(AuthenticatedRouteMixin, {
  model: function(params) {
    if (params.q) {
      return this.store.find('project', params);
    } else {
      return this.store.findAll('project');
    }
  },
  queryParams: {
    q: {
      refreshModel: true
    }
  },
  actions: {
    loading: function(/*transition, route*/) {
      var _this = this;
      this.controllerFor('projects').set('showSearchSpinner', true);

      this.router.one('didTransition', function() {
        _this.controllerFor('projects').set('showSearchSpinner', false);
      });

      return true; // Bubble the loading event
    }
  }
});
```

My issue now is that when I use the parameter query, it works great, but then if I clear the query (with an action, to effectively "go back") then the records fetched by the query stay in the store, so when it does a `findAll()` I have both sets of records, which is not at all what I want. How do I clear out the store before doing `findAll` again?